# Multiway equality test failing

Tags: templates, go, go-templates, revel

So I have the following equality test in a go template

`{{if eq .user.Role "Manager" "Admin"}}`

which should work according to the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and the [1.2 release notes](http://golang.org/doc/go1.2), but I'm not having any luck

To make it more clear .user.Role "Manager" would work, or any equality test that involves only one argument. So something like 
`{{if eq 1 1}}` evaluates correctly, but `{{if eq 1 2 1}}` does not.

Error I get is `3: executing ".../index.html" at : wrong number of args for eq: want 2 got 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities. Either you aren't on version 1.2 (what does `go version` give?) or somewhere in the pipeline the `eq` function was replaced in the template's [FuncMap](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#Template.Funcs). Unfortunately, it's not exported, so I can't think of a good way to know if the latter is the case. If you haven't replaced it, are you using a package that modifies the pipeline? If so, try the rendering without any packages and see if it works.

Comment: I'm quite sure you are right,with a vanilla project it evaluates fine, but this template was evaluated in my revel project, so maybe somewhere in revel it replaces eq. Going on the goose hunt now.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the final solution was to uncomment the eq implementation that revel has in [template.go](https://github.com/robfig/revel/blob/master/template.go).

Answer (score 0):

http://golang.org/src/pkg/text/template/exec_test.go#L71

You would need to export `user` (`User`) to make it accessible.